# How does github commit diff works?

Tags: python, css, user-interface, github, diff

I have always wondered, how does GitHub shows the difference between two commits, it colors the deleted line red,added lines green. I have a project and I want to do something similar, how can one do that? Can someone explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Github uses `git diff`, which by default uses the [Myers algorithm](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/02/12/the-myers-diff-algorithm-part-1/). There are other similar algorithms for doing this (git diff implements a few of them), and they are all a bit complex. I would not recommend you to try to implement any of them for your own project (unless you want to do it as a challenge/for learning).

If you need to do a diff in your own project, I would just wrap around `git diff` or the [unix diff command](https://www.unixtutorial.net/unix-diff/), or use some other package. For instance, Python has a nice module [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) that seem to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean? Coloring using CSS is as simple as setting a `background-color`, so this isn't what you are getting at, I presume.

If you're getting at "finding the differences between two text files", the right search term for that would be "diff": an old unix tool to show the differences between two files. If you've got a Linux shell at your disposal, try `diff -Naur file1.txt file2.txt` -- this'll show you a similar output like the diff on github.

If you need that in python, take a look at https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/